# Missing values in a csv file after having dumped a dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have dumped a dictionary to a csv file, but the last ~400 rows are missing form the file. The dictionary has `10000` values and this is what it looks like:

`dict={'0':252, '1':61, '2':38. '3':91, ..., '9999':17}`. The keys are sorted `0` to `9999` by construction (the dict comes from the application of the `networkx` package).

This is what I have used to do the dumping:

```
import csv
dict=G.edges() #The dictionary comes from an application of the networkx package
writer = csv.writer(open('myfile.csv', 'wb'))
for key, value in dict.items():
    writer.writerow([key, value])
```

**My csv file reports the values until the 9631st row, after which there are no more values. How to fix this?**

This is what my csv file looks like: you clearly see that the 9632nd row is truncated, and there is nothing after it. **How to deal with this?**

```
0     252
1     61
2     38
3     91
...   ...
9630  4
963
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't closed your output file. Try this structure instead:

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for key, value in dict.items():
        writer.writerow([key, value])
```

The `with` keyword will automatically close your output file after the block completes.

Comment: Wouldn't the cleanup associated with program termination ensure that the file gets completely written?

Comment: Yes, assuming that the program terminates. OP never indicated that his program terminates.

Comment: Thanks, bug fixed. Does this problem mean that my procedure was still open, in the sense that Python thought that more data could be added? I thought the size of the dict was used as a proxy for signalling when the computation ended.